How can I get Munich's environmental badge at the last minute?
I am travelling to Munich from Slovakia in two days' time and I need to purchase an environmental badge due to the fact that I will be driving through it (and possibly parking in it) during my stay.
However, I came to discover that the purchase of badges is not as simple as buying it at a petrol station. So I did some research and found out that TÜV SÜD sells these badges.
Does this mean that I can just come to one of these places and get a badge without waiting for too long (assuming that I come during their opening hours)? And can I come without any notice, or is there some kind of protocol for arriving there? And finally, is there any other way to buy this badge that would be simpler?

Note that those badges are not specific to Munich, but are valid in all 39 German cities that have an "Umweltzone", a list can be found here. But did you check that your car meets the requirements for getting an environmental badge?

They can also be ordered online: Emissions stickers for Germany | TÜV SÜD

Fun fact: The green German sticker can also be obtained in Slovakia, at any Dekra vehicle inspection station: https://www.dekra.sk/sk/ekologicka-plaketa-pre-nemecko/. The whole procedure shouldn't take more than a few minutes.


Does this mean that I can just come to one of these places and get a badge without waiting for too long (considering that I come during their open hours)?

Yes, I got one that way years ago and @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo called them to confirm it still works that way. Unless your car is exotic or modified, they should be able to do it in 15 min on the basis of your car registration documentation. They won't promise anything beforehand though, they need to see the documents to decide if they can make a determination on the spot.

And can I come without any notice, or is there some kind of protocol for arriving there?

You don't need an appointment. TÜV Süd is not the only business offering this service so if you're having trouble finding a suitable location, you can also check TÜV Nord or Dekra. You may also be able to pick it up on the way to Germany from ÖAMTC in Austria. ADAC offers comprehensive information on all this.
I might still phone ahead of time to double-check opening times and the like or look up a couple of potential locations in case the first one doesn't work out but you don't need to plan more than this, at least if you travel during the week (Sunday is another story).

And finally, is there any other way to buy this badge that would be simpler?

The same businesses sometimes offer ways to order it abroad, e.g. Dekra but it's probably too late for that if you need to be in Germany in two days.

Even for full technical inspections on German cars, TÜV, KÜS and Dekra usually do not offer appointments, but only 'drop-in' service. I am pretty sure that it will be no problem to get the environment sticker for a foreign car just by showing up at one of their branches.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo so if I go to TUV SUD Service-Center in Burghausen tomorrow during their opening hours, I should be able to get the sticker quickly and without any problems? My car meets the requirements, so that should be fine. And what documents should I bring?

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Yes, that's my thinking too but I don't want to make any promise based on my limited experience. Personally I would look up a couple of locations in case the first one doesn't work out for some reason.

@AdamKinzel I am close to 100% sure that you will have no problems doing it that way. If you drive to Munich on the A94, it will be a shorter detour if you go to TÜV SÜD Service-Center München Ost (instead of Burghausen) if you get there before they close. That branch is outside the environment zone, so you can also get your sticker there.

To be sure, I called TÜV SÛD and asked. Just drop in at any of their service-centers during opening hours with your car registration papers and they will issue you a sticker immediately.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Great, thanks, I edited the answer to mention this!
